# How can send Team ID and Channel id through adaptive card from ms teams app

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am creating an app in ms teams. I want to send Team id and Channel id dynamically but the link button doesn't work when i add team id in params. I read many documents but i can't find any method to send dynamic value

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.2",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "Container",
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "ActionSet",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                        "url": "https://9056-39-42-13-187.ngrok.io/projects/new?teamId={teamId}",
                        "title": "Link"
                    }
                ],
            }
        ],
    }
],
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to send Team id and Channel id dynamically:-

1. You have to install bot in your channel
2. If you send any command or message in channel, request will come at
   server and then from TurnContext you can fetch the values for team &
   channel id and bind it to your Adaptive Card.
3. Now you can send the Adaptive Card as response with team id:

Text

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.2",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "Container",
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "ActionSet",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                        "url": "https://8840-103-132-3-2.ngrok.io/projects/new?teamId=xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx",
                        "title": "Link"
                    }
                ],
            }
        ],
    }
],
}
```

4. Now if you click on Adaptive Card button, it will redirect it to proper URL.

Comment: It showing an error when i click on link "Unable to reach the app try again later"

Comment: You need to provide proper URL configured by you in your application.

Comment: I provide it correct it was working fine 2 day ago but now it start giving me error